# fileUploadListener is not called in JSF 2.3 on Liberty server

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, websphere-liberty, jsf-2.3

We recently upgraded to JSF 2.3, and p:fileUpload stopped calling the fileUploadListener. It still works perfectly when running on Jetty, but not on Liberty.  We are using PrimeFaces 6.0.

Is this a known problem with a workaround?

```
<p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" update="@this docPanel" value="#{documentController.file}" mode="advanced" auto="false" fileLimit="1" 
  fileUploadListener="#{documentController.upload}" styleClass="fileUpload" widgetVar="fileUploadVar" a:onchange="checkSize(); "
  required="true" requiredMessage="#{msgs.msg_val_required}"/>
```

Comment: I 'Improved' your tags

Comment: Did this work with JSF 2.2 on Liberty?

Comment: It did work with JSF 2.2 on Liberty, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Spring Security CSRF didn't recognize the request. We expanded the filter to accept it.

```
   private RegexRequestMatcher unprotectedMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("(/views/StartSystem.*)|(/views/ListDocumentReferences.*)", null);
```